# cannot move out of `keymap.command` which is behind a shared reference

Tags: rust

The following is a mock code for running a terminal command:

```
#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct Keymap {
    pub key: char,
    pub command: String,
}

impl Keymap {
    pub fn new<S: AsRef<str>>(key: char, command: S) -> Self {
        let command = command.as_ref().to_owned();

        Self {
            key,
            command,
        }
    }
}

fn handle_keymap(keymap: &Keymap) {
    println!("Do something with the keymap: {:?}", keymap);

    run_command(keymap.command);
}

fn run_command(command_string: String) {
    let command_string = command_string.replace("test", "best");

    println!("Running this command: {:?}", command_string);
}

fn main() {
    let keymap = vec![Keymap::new('t', "echo 'test'")].into_iter().next().unwrap();

    handle_keymap(&keymap);
}
```

[Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=a9859960d42f01f4eedb703b6b315710)

Right now, there's an error here:

```
error[E0507]: cannot move out of `keymap.command` which is behind a shared reference
  --> src/main.rs:21:17
   |
21 |     run_command(keymap.command);
   |                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ move occurs because `keymap.command` has type `String`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
```

Which can be solved by using `clone()`:

```
run_command(keymap.command.clone());
```

Is there another solution? I think using `clone()` like this isn't good practice?

Comment: Why does `run_command` take `String` instead of `&str`?

Comment: If `run_command()` needs to modify the command it gets passed (seriously?), you should clone inside of `run_command()`, since this is certainly an implementation detail, and shouldn't be reflected in the interface.

Comment: Also note that `new()` should accept `S: Into<String>` instead of `S: AsRef<str>`. Your code will allocate a new string unconditionally, while using `command.into()` would only allocate if needed, and reuse the allocation of a `String` that gets passed in.

Comment: @SvenMarnach "If `run_command` needs to modify the command it gets passed, you should clone inside of `run_command`" as I've said in my answer it should actually pass an owned string and make the caller do the cloning, per the [Rust API Guidelines](https://rust-lang.github.io/api-guidelines/flexibility.html?highlight=clone#caller-decides-where-to-copy-and-place-data-c-caller-control).

Comment: @AleksanderKrauze I don't know the full details here, but from what I've seen, I disagree. It seems very weird for a function named `run_command` to need ownership of the command string that gets passed in. It should _parse_ the string, and that should not require ownership. If for some weird implementation reason it's convenient to have a copy of the string that can be modified, then this is an implementation detail.

Comment: The case is different for the `new()` function. That function clearly needs ownership of the command that is passed in, since it needs to be moved into the struct. Thats why I commented the `new()` function should accept a `String` directly, so the caller can decide where it's allocated.

Comment: I agree that modifying `command` inside `run_command` is very weird and probably shouldn't be done in the first place. My comment only addresses the fact, that when some function wants to have an ownership of some type it should receive it directly from the caller, and not clone it from reference, since this can be very surprising.

Comment: @AleksanderKrauze In the actual app, `run_command` will replace `{}` in the `command` string with user input. Should I do that before passing `command` as an argument to `run_commoand`? https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=3838d73dd3e298d355dea64a00f05aa8

Comment: @alexchenco Why do you do this substitution **inside** function, when it can be done **outside**? I would recommend to fully construct command argument before running this function.

Comment: @AleksanderKrauze Okay, thanks for the advice. I'll see how I can refractor that.

Comment: @AleksanderKrauze I think the refractored code is better. Thanks again! https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=f555ac6f507a3249e37517524e9c13c1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Function `run_command` **takes an ownership** of passed `String` argument. But it cannot do that, since `keymap.command` is behind a shared reference. Depending on what you are trying to do you should do one of the following:

1. If you want `run_command` to change passed command, but not reflect that for the caller you should leave `run_command` as it is now and indeed call `clone()` on `keymap.command`. You could pass `&String` (or `&str`) to `run_command` and clone it inside, but [it is better to leave that decision to the caller](https://rust-lang.github.io/api-guidelines/flexibility.html?highlight=clone#caller-decides-where-to-copy-and-place-data-c-caller-control).
2. If you want `run_command` to **change** actual `keymap.command` pass it a `&mut String` instead. This will also force you to change `handle_keymap` to take `&mut Keymap` instead of `&Keymap`.
3. If you don't want to mutate command inside `run_command` then don't do it and change it to take string by reference `&String` (or event better take advantage of [deref coercion](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch15-02-deref.html#implicit-deref-coercions-with-functions-and-methods) and pass `command` as `&str`).

If you want something different, you will have to be more specific in your question for us to help you.